# Does Django-css app be able to deal with compass?

Tags: django, sass, compass-sass

In my django project, I finally made django-css working, but however, if I do

```
@import "compass"
```

Then the css would break, an emapty css file is generated.

And I have not find any documentation in django-css that says it is able to use with compass. But since it is a fork from django-compressor what has a way to deal with compass style.

So I am wondering here, can I use django-css with compass? If yes, please provide a little tips or hints to use it properly.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to not do so.

[The Official Compass Website](http://compass-style.org/blog/2011/05/09/compass-django/) says develop the CSS on the development machine and commit the CSS to source control, then treat it just as CSS once it's committed and give it to django-css.